# Django Unknown column 'table_name.fieldname_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'm in `production mode` and using `Django==3.1.5` and `MySQL` and trying to find a way to add a field named **`author`** to a model named **`news`** without the need to delete the whole database and recreate it.

> My website isn't completely public yet and is in the preparation state. I can do everything with the database, but I want to find a way not to drop the whole database.

This is the news model and the field:

```
from account.models import User

class News(models.Model):
    ...
    # The user database is a custom user I've defiend
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='auth_news')
```

Every time I restart the `gunicorn` service, I end up facing this error:

[image]

I've tried so many ways to fix this error but no luck! Some of them are:

> ❌ Deleting the `migrations` folder, login to MYSQL and `DELETE FROM django_migrations;` ,then `makemigrations` and `migrate` the `News` model
>
> ❌ Facing with a deprecated package named `South`
>
> ❌ using `python manage.py migrate news --fake`
>
> ❌ using `python manage.py migrate news zero --fake` then remigrate
>
> ❌ using `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb --fake`
>
> ❌ Make initial migrations with `--fake-initial`

When I tried these jobs, all of them worked but none of them added the column `author` to the `news_news` table strangely! Then I tried to add it manually:

> Run `python manage.py sqlmigrate news 0001`
>
> logging in to the SQL database with command `mysql -u root -p`
>
> add the column `author` manually with `ALTER TABLE news_news ADD COLUMN author int(11);`
>
> run command `alter table news_news add foreign key (author) references account_user(id);`
>
> ❌

Still facing the same issue!

I **don't** want to get a backup from the database and drop it!

In the future, I want to add more fields to my models according to my needs so this is not a good solution to drop the whole database like pushing the restart button.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Why did you even delete the migrations? You only needed to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried these commands too, some suggestions were that delete the `migrations` folder and truncate `django_migrations` table.

Comment: You just wanted to add a new field yes? And it was nullable too (you set `null=True` on the field). Then you didn't need to do all these things you did and the above two commands should have done what you wanted. As it is we don't know the current state of your website is. What is the state of the `django_migrations` table? What is the state of your migration files (do you have the old migration files)? If you don't have the old migration files you can only go for a manual fix using SQL.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat My website isn't completely public yet and is in the preparation state. I can do everything with the database, but I want to find a way not to drop the whole database.